# Mix two colors in sass

Tags: css, sass

Say I have these variables in a sass file:

```
$steel-blue: rgba(74, 148, 181,1)!default;
$black: rgba(0, 0, 0,1)!default;

$primary-color: $steel-blue;
$background-color: $black;

$primary-color-overlay: rgba($primary-color,8%);
```

I want to mix `$background-color` with `$primary-color-overlay` which should give me: `#060C0E`.

I tried using `mix()` function but to no avail. It should be as if I have a placed `$primary-color-overlay` on top of `$background-color`.

I'd like to saved the combined color as a variable too.

Comment: With Mix do you get the desired result with background-color: mix($color1,$color2,100%); That's to say that 100% of the first colour will be mixed with the second. Is that what you already tried?

Comment: yes tried this but it always makes $color1 100% so no mix really. @Nathelol

Comment: Could you please add a [mre] so we can play with the code? JSFiddle since SO doesn't support SASS fiddles?

Answer (score 6):

It's not an easy way of doing it and takes some trial and error but you can achieve it with Mix by using the following:

```
background-color: mix($background-color, $primary-color, 92%);
```

You just need to work out the percentage of mixture you want from the two colours. #060C0E isn't a 50/50 mix of the two.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need this :

```
background-color: #4e73df;
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #4e73df 10%, #224abe 100%);
```

Comment: I'd like to save the combined volor as a variable too though

Answer (score 2):

Just to be a little more explicit as to how this is working. Let's take this for example:

`$mixed-color: mix($color1, $color2, 50%);`

There are really 3 different ways to think about that percentage value — use whichever works best in your own brain or for the situation at hand. ;)

1. Think of the percentage as a slider representing the amount of each color to mix in — with 0% being all the way to the "left" (`$color1`), 100% being all the way to the "right" (`$color2`), and 50% being in the middle (an equal amount of both colors).
2. The percentage sets the *opacity* (100% being most opaque) of `$color1` on top of `$color2`.
3. The percentage sets the *transparency* (100% being most transparent) of `$color2` on top of `$color1`.

So to get the color resulting from overlaying `$primary-color` at 8% opacity over `$background-color` either of the following will get you the same thing (although the first one is more how you were approaching it above):

```
$primary-color-overlay: mix($primary-color, $background-color, 8%);
```

```
$primary-color-overlay: mix($background-color, $primary-color, 92%);
```

Answer (score 0):

$steel-blue: rgba(74, 148, 181,1)!default;
$black: rgba(0, 0, 0,1)!default;

$primary-color: $steel-blue;
$background-color: $black;

$primary-color-overlay:linear-gradient(0deg, rgba($primary-color, 0.08), rgba($primary-color, 0.08)), $background-color;

Comment: .body{
  background: $primary-color-overlay;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}


HTML
<div class="body">
  Success!!!
</div>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).