# CSS color-mix result

Tags: css, sass

How can I get the value of the result of `color-mix` two colors?

I need to use a hard-coded value for browsers that do not support the `color-mix` feature.

Comment: is this what  your asking about : https://wikimass.com/sass/mix ?  Have you also seen that post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178272/mix-two-colors-in-sass . Please clarify your question :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus dude, what's not clear? i need the result, the return value so i can use it as a hard coded literal so that stuff works in older browsers .. it is a function and the concept of a result, the return value is quite well understood in coding communities :/

Comment: hi, whats unclear is the tag sass but question about color-mix() which is plain CSS ;) and no code at all to describe what you've done or to demonstrate your issue. bad question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a SASS function that directly corresponds to the CSS `color-mix` function but is performed at compile-time, though other functions exist for color manipulation. You could look into other CSS preprocessor tools that can transpile modern CSS into a syntax compatible with older browsers, but I don't know one myself (and exchanging tool recommendations is beyond the scope of this site).

Otherwise, if you just need to do it for a few colors you can use JavaScript in your browser console to run `getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor` which should return the color assigned to the given element. This will likely return the color in the format passed to the color-mix CSS function.

```js
document.write(getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor);
```

```css
body {
  background: color-mix(in lch, red, blue);
}
```

Comment: the javascript solution is great -- for me, it was easier to just check computed styles in the developer tool!